# Class from Inferred namespace works, but not when explicitly named

Tags: c#, generics, interface

The class I want to use is `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver`. The following works:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
...
var x = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<myType>();
```

However, the following does not:

```
//using System.Web.Mvc;
var x = System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<myType>();
```

The error is:

> The non-generic method 'IDependencyResolver.GetService(Type)' cannot be used with type arguments.

What is the syntax to use without a `using System.Web.Mvc` directive.

I want to have `using System.Web.Http`. There are attributes (`Route` and `RoutePrefix`) which are present in both of these name spaces. `System.Web.Http`  has a far higher usage in this particular code file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic method version `GetService<T>()` is an extensioin method that is delcared in the static class `DependencyResolverExtensions` in the `System.Web.Mvc` namespaces.

This is not the same method as `IDependencyResolver.GetService()` which is declared as non-generic instance method of `DependencyResolver`.

Since you did not import that namespace, the compiler can't find the static class that implements the generic extension method `GetService<T>(this IDependencyResolver ...)`.

As Widi commented, to use this without the `using` statement you would need to call it like this:

```
var x = System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolverExtensions.GetService<myType>(System.Web.Mvc.D‌​ependencyResolver.Current);
```

Comment: Usage of the extention without using statements: `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolverExtensions.GetService<myType>(System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current)`